# How can I use the SOAP API to actually edit the content of a Knowledge Article?

Tags: api, soap-api, knowledge

All I can find in the API is stuff about publishing, deleting, managing... but nothing about directly editing them, and none of the fields on the KnowledgeArticle and KnowledgeArticleVersion I'm working on importing articles from other sources and while I can set a title, summary, creator, etc. I cannot actually put content in the article. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Edit: I have since learned that nearly every field in a __kav is a custom field. I created a field body__cc and it works wonderfully.